# Generate code from specification

Tags: programming-languages, grammar, context-free-grammar, formal-languages

I was wondering what it is the best way to generate code, in a certain programming language P, by using a kind of specification S. Just an example:

S:

```
v = []
for_each x in v:
    print($index, x)
```

P:

```
v = []
for i, x in enumerate(v):
    print(i, x)
```

This is just an example for you in order to understand better my problem. I'm trying to search the best way to do that. Are there some specific algorithms that I can use?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "specification"? Both of your examples look like code in a programming language. Are you asking how to compile one language to another?

Comment: It's a kind of textual specification. It is more similar to a pseudocode. I'd like to use this pseudocode to generate a single Python class.

Comment: There might be a confusion of terminology here. In your words what would be the difference between your pseudocode specification and a programming language? In my book pseudocode is by definition not implementable. Its defining characteristic is that it does not have a well-defined syntax or semantics, but instead works on a do-what-I-mean basis. That is, the author of the pseudocode can just make up functions or syntactic constructs on a whim or even write parts in plain English. If you restrict pseudocode to the point where it can be implemented by a computer program, it's just code.

Comment: Anyway, I still think that what you're basically asking is how to write a compiler. If so, that question is way too broad to tackle in a Stackoverflow post, but you'll find plenty of resources on the Internet.

Comment: Agree with sepp2k that the answer to your question is "write a compiler". This is exactly what compilers do: reading a specification in a certain language, parsing it to determine the intended meaning, and then using that meaning to output a new representation of the same meaning. I would look into books on compilers - maybe a MIT OCW course - and dive in.

Comment: Maybe you need less than a compiler. If S and P basically have the same constructs as in your example, you would not need to go to the level of meaning as a compiler does. For the example, a transducer could suffice, except for maybe the $index / i -correspondence.